# Extracting the sentence where a string is embedded from a text using Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, text-extraction

I want to extract from a text --which is provided as a string variable-- the sentences where a substring belonging in a list of substrings is embedded.  If I can not extract the sentence I would compromise with extracting a span of strings of fixed length before and after the substring of interest.

Perhaps the following image will make things more clear:

[image]

In this image, we see a text that is assigned to a string variable.  The substring highlighted in yellow is the substring of interest and appears 3 times in the given text.  I would like a function that would return the two highlighted sentences (green + yellow).  If I can't extract the sentences I would compromise with extracting a fixed number of words (e.g 20 words) before and after the yellow highlighted string.

The substring will be listed in a list of substrings of interest.

I have found a way to extract the exact substring but not a span of text before and after it as described above.

E.g.,

```
text = 'Την 25/07/2019 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εµπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) µε Κωδικό Αριθµό Καταχώρισης 1801727 η µε αριθµό 78002/ 25-07-2019 απόφασή µας (Α∆Α:  ΩΙΑ7465ΧΙ8-ΤΨΦ), µε την οποία εγκρίθηκε  η  τροποποίηση εν συνόλω του καταστατικού της ανώνυµης εταιρείας µε την επωνυµία  «ΑΛΟΥΜΥΛ, ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΑ ΑΛΟΥΜΙΝΙΟΥ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΙΑ» και αριθµό Γ.Ε.ΜΗ 14492035000 (πρώην Αρ.ΜΑΕ 17520/06/B/88/18) σύµφωνα µε την  από 29.5.2019 απόφαση της Τακτικής Γενικής Συνέλευσης των µετόχων της, στο πλαίσιο εναρµόνισης µε το ν. 4548/2018 «Αναµόρφωση ∆ικαίου Ανωνύµων Εταιρειών», όπως ισχύει. Το εν λόγω καταστατικό µε ηµεροµηνία 29/5/2019 αποτελείται από 33 άρθρα, ως αυτά διαλαµβάνονται στα κεφάλαια Ι έως ΙΧ αυτού.Ο ΠΡΟΪΣΤΑΜΕΝΟΣ ΤΗΣ ∆ΙEΥΘΥΝΣΗΣ                                                                                                     ΙΩΑΝΝΗΣ ΑΡΕΤΑΙΟΣ      1 ΝΕΟ ΚΕΙΜΕΝΟ ΤΟΥ ΚΑΤΑΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ ΤΗΣ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗΣ ΕΤΑΙΡΙΑΣ «ΑΛΟΥΜΥΛ, ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΑ ΑΛΟΥΜΙΝΙΟΥ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΙΑ» με αριθμό ΜΑΕ: 17520/06/Β/88/18 και αριθμό ΓΕΜΗ: 14492035000 όπως προέκυψε ύστερα από την εναρμόνιση με τις διατάξεις των άρθρων του Ν. 4548/2018 με απόφαση της από 29.05.2019 Γενικής Συνέλευσης των μετόχων της  «ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ I ΣΥΣΤΑΣΗ - ΕΠΩΝΥΜΙΑ - ΣΚΟΠΟΣ - ΕΔΡΑ - ΔΙΑΡΚΕΙΑ  Άρθρο 1 Σύσταση - Επωνυμία Συνίσταται Ανώνυμος Εταιρία με την επωνυμία “ΑΛΟYΜΥΛ, ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΑ ΑΛΟYΜΙΝΙΟΥ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΙΑ‘’ και διακριτικό τίτλο ‘’ΑΛΟΥΜΥΛ Α.Ε.’’. Σε περίπτωση συναλλαγής της Εταιρίας με πρόσωπα της αλλοδαπής, θα χρησιμοποιείται η αγγλόφωνη εκφορά της εταιρικής επωνυμίας, ήτοι ‘’ΑLUMΙL ΑLUΜΙNΙUΜ INDUSTRY SA”.»  Άρθρο 2 Σκοπός «Σκοπός της Εταιρίας είναι η ανέγερση και εκμετάλλευση εργοστασίου παραγωγής επιμήκων προϊόντων αλουμινίου με τη μέθοδο διελάσεως και επιφανειακής επεξεργασίας αυτών. Η έρευνα, ο σχεδιασμός, η μελέτη και η εμπορία εξοπλισμού για παραγωγή ηλεκτρικής ενέργειας από ανανεώσιμες πηγές ενέργειας και ειδικότερα αλλά όχι περιοριστικά από ηλιακή ενέργεια. Η εμπορία των προϊόντων αυτών, καθώς και η εμπορία παρεμφερών προϊόντων'

import regex
list_of_strings =['ΑΛΟΥΜΥΛ, ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΑ ΑΛΟΥΜΙΝΙΟΥ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΙΑ', 
                  'ΑΝΕΚ ΤΟΥΡΙΣΤΙΚΗ - ΞΕΝΟΔΟΧΕΙΑΚΗ - ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΩΝ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ', 
 'ATTICA BANK ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΤΡΑΠΕΖΙΚΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ']
regex.findall(r"\L<words>", text, words= list_of_strings)
['ΑΛΟΥΜΥΛ, ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΑ ΑΛΟΥΜΙΝΙΟΥ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΙΑ']
```

What would you propose?

Comment: Does the source of the given string really have no newlines in it, or did you format that string that way to fit one row?

Comment: Do you want https://regex101.com/r/fvdZc9/1? https://ideone.com/2fxQ3l ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the job of regex split.

```
from re import split

split('abc\d{3}','sldkfjsdl abc678 sldkfjsdlk thing')
```

EDIT:

Wrote a generalized splitter.

```
from re import split

def super_split(regex_list,string): 
    answer = [string] 
    for r in regex_list: 
        answer = sum([sum([[s,r] for s in split(r,a)],[])[:-1] for a in answer],[]) 
    return answer 

s = super_split(list_of_strings,text)
```

Did notice that the text you provided is not the full text given in the picture, so I could only test this on what you gave.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how this approach would enable me to meet my goal.  Perhaps you would like to use the text I provide and try out to isolate the string of interest within spans of text that will extend 20 words in either direction or alternatively extract the paragraphs where the string of interest is embedded.

Comment: That would be great, but you didn't provide data that could be copy and pasted. The text is also clearly non-ascii, hence I would need the exact bytes of the strings. Scratch that, I didn't realize you can the text on a single line. Let me play with it a sec.